# Exporting data from Ansys CFD-Post using Power Syntax script

Tags: post-processing, fluid-dynamics, ansys

I've created a Power Syntax script for post-processing transient CFD results from Fluent with 200 timesteps in CFD-Post. The script creates ~200 planes for which it uses the in-built massFlowAve function to calculate their mass flow-weighted average temperatures which will then be applied as reference temperatures in conjunction with y-plus heat transfer coefficients to a thermo-mechanical FE model.

I set the script up to tabulate the data in the Table Viewer and then export them as a .csv file but have realised the limits of columns / rows is nowhere near large enough to accommodate the amount of data. Is there a way to extend the limits of Tables in Table Viewer? Alternatively, is there a better way to export the data as a .csv file?

Many thanks for any help.